# C# VS error: Class does not contain a constructor (even when adding one in the class itself)

Tags: c#, constructor

On VS C# Express, I get this error when running the code below:

> 'myComponent.SettingsComponentAttributes' does not contain a
>   constructor that takes 1 arguments.

I have tried adding a constructor in the class itself but the same message applied to the new constructor:

```
public override void CreateAttributes()
{
    m_attributes = new SettingsComponentAttributes(this);
}

public SettingsComponentAttributes(SettingsComponentAttributes obj)
{
}
```

Comment: You have to create a constructor that takes 1 argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class doesn't declare any constructors, therefore it's equivalent to having a single parameterless constructor:

```
public SettingsComponentAttributes()
{
}
```

You're trying to pass an argument (`this`) into the constructor - which isn't going to work. You'll need to either change your constructor call, or declare an appropriate constructor.

You should *also* look at the error message carefully and work out why you needed to ask on Stack Overflow. Which bit of the message wasn't clear to you? Revise that aspect of your C# knowledge. Understanding error messages is a very important part of being a good developer, and this one is fairly clear:

- You're trying to use a constructor with 1 argument
- No such constructor exists

Comment: Thank you very much, yes indeed I need to go back to fundamentals, just watched this informative [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Waq_xVXNJCQ) about contructors. starting to grasp the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Default constructors are parameterless, so if you want to create a constructor which accepts one argument you have to create it yourself

Something like this

```
public class SettingsComponentAttributes : GH_ComponentAttributes
{
    public override void CreateAttributes()
    {
      m_attributes = new SettingsComponentAttributes(this);
    }

    public SettingsComponentAttributes(SettingsComponentAttributes obj)
    {
       // Do your fancy work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class constructor that takes 1 arguement, e.g.:

```
    public SettingsComponentAttributes(SettingsComponentAttributes other)
    {
        // Initialise.
    }
```

Comment: That's a constructor without *any* parameters, and it won't compile due to `Public` and `Class`, too...

Comment: It wasn't a matter of reading the *question* thoroughly - the *text* in your answer was already correct, but your sample code didn't match the text.

Comment: Thanks @Duane, sorry what is the 'other' doing?

Comment: It's just a parameter to demonstrate. It could be a reference to another instance of your `SettingsComponentAttributes` class.

Comment: Thanks @Duane, when I add the constructor there is an error saying 'method should have a return type'. I will just add 'void'

Comment: @arthurmani if you need to add a return type to a constructor then you are not declaring the constructor correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got a constructor that takes 1 argument

```
public SettingsComponentAttributes(int i)
```